# R function to tag multiple entries to a sequence

Tags: r, function

I want to create a **function** in **R**, which can tag the below entries by a sequence(serial # order) in which they appear. Below entries repeat by 2, so in this case:

```
numbers: 1   1   2   2........
 tag:    1   2   1   2........
```

Comment: Try  `ave(numbers, numbers, FUN=seq_along)` or `sequence(rle(numbers)$lengths)`

Comment: That was easy!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying akrun's answer here so the question doesn't look unanswered

```
numbers<-c(1,1,2,2,2,3)
tag<-ave(numbers, numbers, FUN=seq_along)
tag
# [1] 1 2 1 2 3 1
```